# Reading from an NFC reader directly into a desktop web application?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, libusb, lib-nfc, webnfc

I have LibNFC working from the Linux terminal recognising my ACR122U Reader, and I wanted to know if there was a method for it to work through Chrome on a Linux Desktop as it is really similar to Android Support, with all the NFC device handling done by libnfc and the browser just has to know about this library instead of every type usb or other device than can do NFC.

I have tried using the WebNFC API to connect it :

```js
document.getElementById("scanButton").addEventListener("click", async () => {
    log.innerHTML = "NFC Register started...";

    try {
      const ndef = new NDEFReader();
      await ndef.scan();
      log.innerHTML = ("> Scan started");
  
      ndef.addEventListener("readingerror", () => {
        log.innerHTML = ("Argh! Cannot read data from the NFC tag. Try another one?");
      });
  
      ndef.addEventListener("reading", ({ message, serialNumber }) => {
        log.innerHTML = ("ID  ${serialNumber} logged @" + dt.toLocaleTimeString());   });
    } catch (error) {
      log.innerHTML = (error);
    }
  });

  document.getElementById("stopButton").onclick = function(){
    log.innerHTML = "NFC Register stopped @ " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    };
```

but I'm met with `Error: NFC Permission Request denied`

and the WebUSB API to connect it:

```js
var usbd = {};
let device;
let deviceEndpoint = 0x02;

let powerUpDevice = new Uint8Array([0x62,0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00, 0x00]).buffer;
let getCardUID = new Uint8Array([0xff,0xca,0x00,0x00,0x04]).buffer;

(function() {
    'use strict';

    usbd.authorize = function(){
        navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [{ vendorId: 0x072f }] })
            .then(selectedDevice => {
                device = selectedDevice;
                console.log(device.configuration.interfaces[0].interfaceNumber);
                console.log(device.manufacturerName);
                console.log(device.productName);
                console.log(device);
                return device.open()
                    .then(() => {
                        if (device.configuration === null) {
                            return device.selectConfiguration(1);
                        }
                    });
            })
            .then(() => device.claimInterface(0))
```

but I'm met with `Error: ...blocked because it implements a protected interface class` i.e. not supported, so that's a no go.

Is there a way to incorporate the libusb/libnfc libraries or any other method to directly connect an NFC reader to read into a web browser/application?

Comment: You'll need users to download or run a program that runs a `localhost` webserver which your web-application can connect to to use local hardware - this is how Dell's Service Tag lookup feature works, for example.

Comment: Ooh, thanks for that and the great example; I think that might be my plan B perhaps, but I really wanted it to be a standalone web application without extra programs to install. At least then it would be able to run on multiple platforms but yes thank you so much for that solution -- I'll fall back on that if all else fails :)

Comment: Have you tried running your WebNFC example in an https:// web-app (e.g. using letsencrypt free certificates)? As far as I understand, you need to be in a secure context in order to access the NFC reader (that's why the WebNFC online experiment should work from this https:// configured website https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-nfc/ )

Comment: @FSp yeah I use the application in both a https://localhost environment and a https domain address for testing the application. I think it's mainly the ACR122U reader that's the issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Web NFC** is supported on Android only as of February 2021. See https://web.dev/nfc/

The **WebUSB** error suggests you're requesting an interface that implements a protected class (among those below):

```cpp
  // USB Class Codes are defined by the USB-IF:
  // https://www.usb.org/defined-class-codes
  const uint8_t kProtectedClasses[] = {
      0x01,  // Audio
      0x03,  // HID
      0x08,  // Mass Storage
      0x0B,  // Smart Card
      0x0E,  // Video
      0x10,  // Audio/Video
      0xE0,  // Wireless Controller (Bluetooth and Wireless USB)
  };
```

I wonder if that's a linux thing though as I was able to communicate with the ACR122U and   SCL3711 NFC reader USB devices through WebUSB. See https://github.com/beaufortfrancois/chrome-nfc

Did you give a try to **WebHID** by any chance first? See https://web.dev/hid

Comment: Is the example for your Chrome NFC running on WebUSB? I assumed that the chrome.nfc.* code lines meant that it was geared to the Chrome App collection rather than running directly off the web, if that makes sense? I tried it out and it works for me, but the chrome-nfc.js wouldn't be able to be applied into something running on a live website, right?

Regarding WebHID I filled out the vendorID and all linking to the ACR122U but it wasn't recognised; I'll try keep at it and fiddle with it but no luck :/

Comment: As you can read in https://github.com/googlearchive/chrome-nfc/compare/master...beaufortfrancois:master, chrome-nfc.js should be working as well in a browser environment as it uses WebUSB, not just a Chrome App env.

Comment: I tried the sample on your repo that uses WebUSB and ran it through Chrome on Linux and Windows but I keep getting the same error that the NFC reader is a protected class and `(Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Access denied.)` so I'm still unsure how it worked for you, and I don't think there's a bypass for this either. It does work as a Chrome App though on Linux bizarrely, but as it's being phased out I don't think I'll put a focus on developing for that, right?
WebHID doesn't seem to find the reader as a 'compatible device' so I'm back to sqaure one...

Comment: Can you look in `chrome://usb-internals/`, inspect your device, and share the output on both windows and linux so that we can understand what is going on?

Comment: Sorry for the late response @François Beaufort !
ChromeNFC Sample on Linux : https://ibb.co/5LG8DhL
USB Internals Screen on Linux : https://ibb.co/319857B

ChromeNFC Sample on Windows : https://ibb.co/9ncyzfc
USB Internals Screen on Windows : https://ibb.co/Bg1JSsK

Site Information in Chrome for Both OS' : https://ibb.co/ZzJLpmG

Comment: Can you fully expand the "Interface 0" item so that I can inspect the Class Code?

Comment: Yep, here you go; the Linux window has two Interface 0 elements, one in the main section and the other in the configuration descriptor : https://ibb.co/mJmxz5F / https://ibb.co/6Pw1Y5H . 
On Windows I can only read the main section's Interface 0: https://ibb.co/Z1TBmWs

Comment: From what I can read, the class Code is 11 (smart card) which is blocked by WebUSB sadly. IIRC, this didn't happen with my ACR122U device. Note that I'm working on adding this bit of info to about:usb-internals to help web developers. See https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/2739609

From there then, I'd suggest you try WebHID. Understanding HID reports and report descriptors through collections will be key to your comprehension of this device. Tools like Wireshark and https://webhid-collections.glitch.me/ can help you reverse-engineering it.

Comment: yeah, I was afraid you'd say that, but I digress. Thank you so much for all of your help and the extra resources; I'm going to try and give WebHID a whirl now and see if I can get it to work with my reader :)